# smarty error seen in JS code

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I am trying to use tiny mce (JS editor ) in a web page rendered by Smarty 3. 
But when I use the below code , It throws the following error

> The specific message was: Syntax Error
>   in template
>   "/home/xxx/xxx/websites/site.local/views/xxx/newnl.html.tpl"
>   on line 564 "m.add({title : "Subject
>   {test}", onclick : function() {" -
>   Unexpected " : ", expected one of: "}"
>   , " "

Code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/./js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

tinymce.create("tinymce.plugins.yyyPlugin", {
    createControl: function(n, cm) {
        switch (n) {
            case "tm_menubutton":
            var c = cm.createMenuButton("tm_menubutton", {
                title : "yyy",
                image : "http://127.0.0.1/./img/yyy_logo.png",
                icons : false
            });
            c.onRenderMenu.add(function(c, m) {
                m.add({title : "Subject {test}", onclick : function() {
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, "{test}");
                }});

 });
}
}
});
</script>
```

Could anyone have a look at it ?
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem like that the code you pasted is where the error is being triggered. What is the line 564?

Comment: this is just a snippet of code where I am seeing the error . The file is a huge one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should enclose your JS code using the `{literal}{/literal}` tag if you haven't. This prevents Smarty from parsing what's in between so that the JS code is not being mistaken for PHP code.