# Syntax Error while implementing Google Map Javascript API with Smarty

Tags: javascript, google-maps, smarty

I am implementing google map api for my website, but smarty is throwing some kind of syntax error in the javascript module. This is really surprising because I just copied the code from examples given on google's website.

Smarty Says:

> on line 236 "var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};" - Unexpected ": ", expected one of: "}"

and my Javascript tag is:

```
 function initMap() {
   var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 4,
     center: myLatLng
   });

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     title: 'Hello World!'
   });
 }
```

I don't understand what the problem is and how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `position` as a `new google.maps.LatLng([lat], [lng])` object.

```
function initMap() {
   var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('-25.363', '131.044');

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 4,
     center: myLatLng
   });

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     title: 'Hello World!'
   });
 }
```

Comment: Although my answer worked out for you, it didn't help to know the source of your problem. So, i think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429012/smarty-error-seen-in-js-code/5429290#5429290) can help you with the smarty error you're getting.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I didnt get to know the root cause of the problem myself. Have to go through with the documentation of smarty for that.

Comment: I have posted a link for an answer that might help you with that on my previous comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429012/smarty-error-seen-in-js-code/5429290#5429290 <- this one.

Answer (score 1):

Changing

`var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};`

to,

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('-25.363', '131.044');
```

actually worked.

Thanks to the person who posted the answer at first but then deleted it somehow.

Comment: I hadn't seen that the question had to do with smarty. So i thought my answer wouldn't help at all. I've undeleted it.